# Android Development: Passing a parameter into an onClickListener()

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Basically I am creating buttons within a for loop, I need each button to return a different value when pressed.

I had thought that creating my own onClickListener() and passing in the data needed as a parameter when it is initialized would work. It appears there are no syntax errors with what I came up with but when a button is clicked at run time the app crashes.

Heres a simplified version of what I've got thus far.

```
int counter = 1;
for( Program element :  someList)
    {
    //some other code for dynamically creating textviews to stick the buttons in

    //code which creates the buttons on the fly
    moreInfo = new Button(this);
    moreInfo.setText("More Info");  
    moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new DynamicOnClickListener(counter));
    counter++;

    }
```

The custom listener class

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DynamicOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

    int counter;
    public DynamicOnClickListener(int acounter) {
         this.counter = acounter;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("DynamicOnClickListener","1");
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 }
```

So in theory if this worked each button would return a different number, hope that makes sense.

Comment: How is it crashing? (logcat)

Comment: logcat is much needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Toast.makeText` takes string resource id as a second argument. Your counter value is not a valid resource id that's way you are getting an error. You need to pass a `String` instead of `int` and it will work.

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(counter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple listeners you can use setTag()

```
moreInfo = new Button(this);
moreInfo.setText("More Info");
moreInfo.setTag(new Integer(counter));
moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new DynamicOnClickListener();
```

then, in your listener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.v("DynamicOnClickListener","1");
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((Integer)v.getTag()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```